# A question about the differentiability conditions for a fractional power

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Now consider the fractional power $$f(x)=z^{m/n}=|z|^{m/n}(\cos \frac{mArgz}{n}+i \sin \frac{mArgz}{n})$$
Since $f(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and is therefore differentiable, we can obtain its derivative as follows
$$ f'(z)=\frac {m}{n}r^{m/n}\left(\cos \frac{m
Arg z}{n}+\sin \frac{mArgz}{n}\right)\frac {1}{z}= \frac {m}{n} \frac {f(z)}{z}   $$
if we confine $f(x)$ as a single-valued function.

Please tell me why the condition $z \neq 0$ can be dropped in the calculation of $f'(z)$ if $m/n$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: maybe because if $f(z) = z^a$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$ only if  $a \in \mathbb{N}$. if $a = 1/2$ for example, $f(z)$ has a branching point at $0$, and it has two differents branches : two different possible values, depending of a starting point and a path on which it is supposed to be continuous. $f^{1/2} = e^{0.5 \ln z}$ which is different when $\ln 1 = 0$ or $\ln 1 = 2i \pi$

Comment: $z^{1/2} = e^{0.5 \ln z}$